# Translating Object in OpenTK

Tags: c#, .net, windows, graphics, opentk

Hello I'm currently using the

```
 Vector3 translation = new Vector3( tx, ty, tz);
        GL.Translate(translation);
```

Way of translating an object in OpenTK where the Vector3 values are from -1 to 1

How do I change this and make the values of a movable object to go pixel wise that way I
can set up a scene based on the user's screen size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In legacy OpenGL 1.x, you can achieve this by setting up an orthographic projection with [GL.Ortho](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

```
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Ortho(0, Width, Height, 0, -1, 1);

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Translate(1.0f, 0, 0); // translates by 1 pixel
```

Be forewarned that this will make your application difficult to port to high-resolution (4K) monitors. I would advise using a resolution-independent approach if at all possible. For example:

```
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Ortho(-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1);

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Translate(1.0f / Width, 0, 0); // translates by 1 pixel
```

Comment: Now nothing is showing up on my screen. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Here is my draw code:

GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textID);
                    GL.Translate(0.5, 0.7, 0);
                    drawObject(100, 20, 0.15f, 0.15f);
                    GL.Translate(-0.7, -0.3, 0);
                    drawObject(100, 60, 0.15f, 0.15f);
                    GL.Translate(0.8, -0.5, 0);
                    drawObject(100, 100,0.15f, 0.15f);
                    GL.Translate(1, 1, 0);

                    GL.PopMatrix();
                    GL.Flush();

Comment: [code](GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D, textID);
                    GL.Translate(0.5, 0.7, 0);
                    drawObject(100, 20, 0.15f, 0.15f);
                    GL.Translate(-0.7, -0.3, 0);
                    drawObject(100, 60, 0.15f, 0.15f);
                    GL.Translate(0.8, -0.5, 0);
                    drawObject(100, 100,0.15f, 0.15f);
                    GL.Translate(1, 1, 0);

                    GL.PopMatrix();
                    GL.Flush(); )